# Issue with ggplot2 geom_line not plotting all levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a multiple line graph with data that looks like the following -

```
 Frequency    Spectrum     Time
 0.000000000  0.0222398397 Pre 
 0.004882812  0.0852786647 Pre
 0.009765625  0.1601532116 Pre
 0.000000000  0.023070938  Post1 
 0.004882812  0.065029561  Post1
 0.009765625  0.170168218  Post1
 0.000000000  0.002796956  Post2     
 0.004882812  0.0650295614 Post2
 0.009765625  0.1601532116 Post2
 0.000000000  0.002796956  Post3     
 0.004882812  0.0650295614 Post3
 0.009765625  0.1601532116 Post3
```

I am using the following code to plot the line graph:

```
    fullpsd %>% ggplot(aes(x = Frequency, y = Spectral)) +
                geom_line(size = 2, aes(color = time))
```

When I do this, only 3 of the 4 lines show up on the graph. I have already converted the columns in the data frame to be numeric and factor. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The Frequency and Spectrum valuers for `Post2` and `Post3` are identical. Hence they are plotted on top of each other making one "invisible".

Comment: You have `time` but R is case sensitive, it should be `aes(color = Time)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the image from this link [Geom_line Issues Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZDIj.png) is what you see, then this is caused by your `Post2` & `Post3` data being identical as mentioned by @stefan. When I changed `Post3` last `Frequency` to be `0.012` [Geom_line Resolved Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js5GE.png), you can see that the line of `Post2` level is there but is overlapped by `Post3` data.

There are 2 ways that you can fix this overlapping issues.

1. Add some offsets value or
2. Make it a stack chart

Comment: Thanks so much! This is just a subset of my larger dataframe, where the values of Spectrum actually are different by group (none of the groups are completely identical).

Comment: Sure thing. You can adjust the width of the line and line style if you have too many levels and when other values are close to each other. This can help all levels to be more visible  from the plot. Also, you can try to create a subplots if that helps to better visualize your story.